# How can a single number represent a color?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have this numpy array

```
[[  0   1   2 ... 397 398 399]
 [  0   1   2 ... 397 398 399]
 [  0   1   2 ... 397 398 399]
 ...
 [  0   1   2 ... 397 398 399]
 [  0   1   2 ... 397 398 399]
 [  0   1   2 ... 397 398 399]]
# shape = (800, 400)
```

That, when represented using matplotlib displays a variety of colors for each element (number) of the array.

[image: Output]

And I was wondering how a single number can represent a color? As far as I know, you need at least 3 values (RGB) to represent a color.

Here's the full code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = [i for i in range(400)]
arr = np.array([colors for i in range(800)])

plt.imshow(arr)
plt.show()
```

Comment: since your shape is `(800,400)`, and not `(800,400,3)`, you only have one channel. So its black and white. matplotlib is just displaying it using the `viridis` color map, which is the default

Comment: matplotlib uses color maps that map an index to a color, that's how you can read a color from an int. For example, your can use the option `cmap="gray"` to have variations of the gray color. Othe more maps exist : https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html